# data format changed when importing data from Mysql to Hbase

Tags: mysql, hbase, sqoop

I am using sqoop to import data from Mysql into Hbase.
It works fine but there is one issue.
As i read from Sqoop documentation , sqoop converts mysql data into String and then store it in Hbase.
However this would be problem for me as i will have to export data back from Hbase to Mysql and at that time , how will sqoop deduce data type information for the Hbase data ?
Someone please help for solution to this problem.

Comment: Can someone please reply.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is - during export, just export it to a temporary table in MySql side. At that point the datatype will be different. Then write a query to insert them to the original MySql table from the temp table and during this time filter out unexpected data or convert datatype.

I faced pretty similar issue with timestamp datatype as in Hive I was storing it as bigint. During export I first inserted them as it is to make Sqoop export works. If its successful then I run a query that actually load those data from temp table to original table while converting the data at the same time. Hope it helps.